# Several links on a page that need to open in a fancybox window

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a page with several links. Each of these links should open in a fancybox window. The structure of the HTML is something like this:

```
<a href="#inline" class="fancybox"> Link 1 </ a>
<div id="inline"> Content for link 1 that opens in a fancybox window </ div>

<a href="#inline" class="fancybox"> Link 2 </ a>
<div id="inline"> Content for link 2 that opens in a fancybox window </ div>

<a href="#inline" class="fancybox"> Link 3 </ a>
<div id="inline"> Content for link 3 that opens in a fancybox window </ div>
```

By clicking on any of the links will open a fancybox window, but not always with the right content. That's not so strange, because all the content divs have the same ID. What's the best solution to open the correct content in the fancybox window for each link?

Edit:
I think my problem is solved. I use the code below:

```
<a href="#1" class="fancybox"> Link 1 </ a>
<div class="inline" id="1"> Content for link 1 that opens in a fancybox window </ div>

<a href="#2" class="fancybox"> Link 2 </ a>
<div class="inline" id="2"> Content for link 2 that opens in a fancybox window </ div>

<a href="#3" class="fancybox"> Link 3 </ a>
<div class="inline" id="3"> Content for link 3 that opens in a fancybox window </ div>
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: You should never same ID for more than one element in page.

Comment: use different `ids` and similar `class` for CSS styles ?

Answer (score 0):

You should never have the same `ID` for more than 1 elements on a page. If you want to apply similar `CSS` styles or bind multiple elements to a javascript you should use a similar `class` instead.

Something like [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZeB5/)

#### Sample Code

```
<a class="fancy_link" id="link_1" href="#!">Content</a>
<a class="fancy_link" id="link_2" href="#!">Content</a>
<a class="fancy_link" id="link_3" href="#!">Content</a>
```

Comment: I am familiar with the fact that all elements must have an unique ID, but I do not know how I have to handle this in jquery. Do you know how to do is in Jquery?

Comment: I think my problem is solved. I use the code below:

    <a href="#1" class="fancybox"> Link 1 </ a>
    <div class="inline" id="1"> Content for link 1 that opens in a fancybox window </ div>
    
    <a href="#2" class="fancybox"> Link 2 </ a>
    <div class="inline" id="2"> Content for link 2 that opens in a fancybox window </ div>
    
    <a href="#3" class="fancybox"> Link 3 </ a>
    <div class="inline" id="3"> Content for link 3 that opens in a fancybox window </ div>

Is this code correct?